# How can i submit our website in AOL search engine?

Tags: search

How can I submit our website in the AOL search engine?

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters!! We do not allow new users to create links to their own sites. Your question is solid enough without it. Cheers!!

Comment: There is no need to submit your site to any search engine these days.   Search engines use crawlers that will find your site as soon as they get some links to them.   Because links are an important ranking factor, submitting your site before it has links is pointless.  Rather than submitting your site, focus on getting a few links to it.

Answer (score 3):

AOL [is powered by Bing now](https://about.ads.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/post/january-2016/bing-powers-aol-search). So if you've submitted to Bing, you're good to go as far as AOL.

Here's how to submit to Bing:

https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/submit-urls-to-bing-62f2860a