# How to force aol and yahoo search engines to index my site

Tags: yahoo

I have researched extensively but have not found a solution. I own a site dedicated to replica swords and would like to have it indexed on AOL and Yahoo search engines. Currently, I am already indexed on Google and now aim to be indexed on AOL and Yahoo as well.

Could you guide me through the process of force indexing on Yahoo, specifically? Do they have a webmaster portal similar to Google Search Console?

Comment: Yahoo is powered by Bing search. That's where you need to focus your efforts.

Comment: oh, so i need to get my website indexed in bing webmaster. And Try to get rank on bing. More rank means more indexing on yahoo. Right?

Comment: It looks like AOL is also "Powered by Bing." https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/129430/how-can-i-submit-our-website-in-aol-search-engine

Comment: My experience is that Yahoo/Bing tend to find my pages without my ever telling them anything.  I do however, have the site in Bing webmaster.